# Matrix being equal

Tags: matrices

If $G = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} a,b\in \mathbb{R} : a \neq 0\right\}$ 
and assume $G$ is a group under matrix multiplication.

Assume that $H = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}: t\in\mathbb{R}, t \neq 0\right\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.
 Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup,

take $g=\begin {pmatrix}a &b \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix} \in G$ and $g'=\begin {pmatrix}a'&b' \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix} \in G$

If $gH=\begin {pmatrix}a &at+b \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$
and $Hg'=\begin{pmatrix} a' & b'+t \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ where $a,b,t \in \mathbb{R}$

Show that $gH=Hg'$

I don't really know where to start. My friend told that let $a=a'$ and show that the
$\text{span} (at+b) =\text{span}(b'+t)$.
Even then I don't know how to approach this problem

Comment: Do you mean actual equality? Where did $a'$, $b'$ come from?

Comment: oh right, I may as well post the whole question

Comment: If you choose $g\in G$ and $h\in H$, what is $ghg^{-1}$ equal to? Is this equal to a matrix in $H$? (If so, the group $H$ is normal.)

Comment: I understand how to do that method, but my homework requires me to do it by showing the left coset is equal to the right coset

Comment: Oh. Okay, then do you have a description of the coset $gH$ in English?

Comment: you have the answer, $x\in gH \Leftrightarrow \exists h\in H : x=gh$ then taking $h'=ghg^{-1} \in H$ you get $gh=ghg^{-1}g=h'g$ and thus $x\in Hg$. so you prove $x\in gH\Leftrightarrow x\in Hg$.

Comment: @MJ73550 : He has to do it with cosets.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Fix a matrix $g= \pmatrix{a&b\cr 0&1\cr}\in G$. Then $gH = \left\{ \pmatrix{a&at+b\cr 0&1\cr} : t\in \mathbb R\right\}$. Since $a$ is invertible, $at+b$, as $t$ ranges over $\mathbb R$, produces all the real numbers; thus, we could also write $gH = \left\{ \pmatrix{a&T\cr 0&1\cr} : T\in \mathbb R\right\}$.

Now you need to find a matrix $g'=\pmatrix{a'&b'\cr0&1\cr}$ such that $Hg'$ produces the same set of matrices. You calculated that $Hg'=\left\{ \pmatrix{a'&b'+t\cr 0&1\cr} : t\in \mathbb R\right\}$. Once again, $b'+t$ will produce all real numbers, as $t$ ranges over $\mathbb R$, so $Hg'=\left\{ \pmatrix{a'&T\cr 0&1\cr} : T\in \mathbb R\right\}$.

To make sure this is the same set as $gH$, you must have $a'=a$. ($b'$ is arbitrary.) Thus, you can pick $g'=\pmatrix{a&0\cr 0&1}$, and you will have $gH=Hg'$, for any $g\in G$. Thus, every left coset equals a right coset (and vice versa), making the group $H$ normal.

Comment: Could you explain why you chose $g'=\pmatrix{a&0\cr 0&1}$, or can you pick any matrix for g'

Comment: You can pick any value for $g'$'s $b$, but $g'$'s $a$ must be the same as $g$'s $a$. In other words, for all $b,c\in \mathbb R$, $H \pmatrix{a&b\cr 0&1\cr} = H \pmatrix{a&c\cr 0&1\cr}$.